# How can I be notified when a project's items are changed?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

I am writing a Visual Studio extension, and I need to know if new project items or projects are added or removed to accurately update the information contained within my extension. How can I be notified when this occurs? There are various events offered by the DTE and Solution objects, but the documentation clearly states it's for internal use only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was informed on MSDN forums to just use the events even though they are marked as Microsoft Internal Use Only. Some like DocumentEvents didn't seem to function correctly.